# DC barrel jack layout

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, layout

[image]

1) I am using this DC barrel connector in my PCB and I want to make sure that when connecting a Center-positive power supply, my positive pin will be (1) and my two negatives will be (2) & (3), am I correct ?
2) my 2nd question is, do I need to connect the two -VE pins together in the pcb, despite they will be disconnected when the power supply is plugged in ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 is the center pin, so it will be positive.

2 is the outside contact, so it will be negative.

3 is the sense pin that is disconnected from the outside contact when a plug is inserted. It should be connected to the sense connection when one exists, otherwise is should be left unconnected.

Comment: So, in the PCB I don't have to connect 2 and 3, right ? and I will keep pin 3 floating ?

Comment: Assuming no sense connection, correct.

Comment: I have two more quick questions, do I need to open another question ? 1) can I use 2.1mmx5.5mm adapters with 2mmx5.5mm dc barrel jack ? 2) In the top left drawing, it says the pin width is 3-1(+-0.2). What does 3-1 means ?

Comment: 1) Maybe. You may need to squeeze the barrel just a tiny bit to assure a positive connection to the pin. 2) I'm not certain, but I think it means that each of the three pins is 1±0.2mm in width (since it's an en dash rather than a hyphen).